# Pandas boolean indexing: matching a set

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I am trying to figure out how to extract the entries in a Pandas dataframe where the values in one column match a given set. Here is an example:

```
num = 5
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((num,3)),index = np.arange(num),columns = ['ID','color','shape'])
df['color'] = ['red','red','blue','blue','yellow']
df['shape'] = ['square','triangle','triangle','circle','circle']
df['ID'] = np.arange(num,num+5)
```

If I want to select only the `'blue'` entries I can do `df[df.color == 'blue']`, and even get the `ID`s: `df[df.color == 'blue'].ID`, and then perform additional manipulations that way. How is this extended to set of such criteria? If I want to return all the entries that are either `blue` or `yellow`, or some general set
`colors = ['blue','yellow','pink']`
the most obvious thing (to me) would be

```
df[df.color in colors]
```

but this gives: `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

What's the correct Pandas way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `isin`:

```
df[df.color.isin(colors)]
```

Output:

```
   ID   color     shape
2   7    blue  triangle
3   8    blue    circle
4   9  yellow    circle
```